# How do I find/use this business card template for displaying work?

Tags: presentation-design

I've seen lots of people on freelancer.com using this (see link below) to present their finished logo for clients. It looks awesome and I want to do the sames but I don't know where/how this is being done, can someone explain? thanks

[Business card example](https://cdn5.f-cdn.com/contestentries/1372818/28841391/5b4eddd4b3f9e_thumb900.jpg)

Comment: Literally, google free templates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to create your own template for such an image in Photoshop.  The beauty of creating your own template is that your work won't look like all those others who are using a pre-created template.  If lots of people are using the same template, then I think that's reason enough not to use it.

To create one, all you really need is a photograph of a piece of paper or card. For good results the lighting in the photograph needs to accentuate the surface texture of the paper.  Textured papers such as laid paper, or watercolour paper are ideal.

The logo is added as a skewed Smart Object with Layer Effects added: usually a Bevel & Emboss, Inner Shadow, and Drop Shadow.

The logo is then clipped to a texture layer (which is a copy of the surface of the paper) which has been altered using the High Pass filter, and the layer mode set to Hard Light.

This makes it possible to create embossing effects for any logo. You simply edit the Smart Object, and place your own logo in it, save it and close the Smart Object, and the artwork is updated in the main document.

Here's an example I made, showing the arrangement of layers.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for sharing this, i'll definitely be giving this a go!